# SPARQL 1.1 support in 4store?

Tags: rdf, sparql, 4store

I am using BIND ( ) to select and Insert triples, from and to 4store.

The following SELECT works,

```
PREFIX Sensor: <http://cei.usc.edu/Equipment.owl#>
SELECT * 
WHERE {
    ?subject100 Sensor:test1 "100"
    BIND("1000" as ?x) .
} LIMIT 10
```

But when I try to do a INSERT WHERE, it fails

```
PREFIX Sensor: <http://cei.usc.edu/Equipment.owl#> 
INSERT {  
    ?subject Sensor:test510 ?value  . 
    }  
WHERE { 
    { 
    ?subject100 Sensor:test1 "100" . 
    BIND("200" as ?value)  
    } 
UNION
    { 
    ?subject99 Sensor:test1 "99" . 
    BIND("300" as ?value)  
    } 
    }
```

error: BIND cannot be used with SPARQL 1.0 at line 1 of operation 0

I am running Latest 4Store v1.1.4 20-Sep-2011

I tried the above INSERT WHERE with a different SPARQL Store and it worked. BIND is a new construct in SPARQL 1.1 so I am not sure if it is supported in 4Store.

Comment: I don't think the SELECT is working either, you won't get any values for ?x.

Answer (score 5):

BIND is not supported in 4store 1.1.4. It will probably be supported in the next version. There has been some discussion about this already.